# Selenium err0r | Message: 'operadriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

Where here error?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\operadriver_win64.zip\operadriver_win64\operadriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

The path is specified, specified with the help argument `executable_path`. What's wrong?

Comment: You've not extracted the zip? `operadriver_win64.zip\` is in the file path... Perhaps uncompressed the file first?

Answer (score 0):

**r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\operadriver_win64.zip\operadriver_win64\operadriver.exe')**

This is wrong , set path properly

**webdriver_service = service.Service('C:\Users\Kris\Downloads\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.2\operadriver.exe')**

Comment: Me need exactly opera